# What IFS actually is in bash?

Tags: bash, ifs

The output of env does not contain IFS, so it isn't not an environment variable, so what it actually is? Is it just a global variable?

`IFS="C" bash -c 'echo X"$IFS"X'` if it is an variale, why this line command not override it?

Comment: It's a normal shell variable.

Comment: [Input Field Separator](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS), [Shell Variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03)

Comment: Use `set` to see all the shell variables. `env` only shows environment variables.

Comment: Then how to check whether a variable is global or environ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What IFS actually is in bash?

It is a variable.

> The output of env does not contain IFS

Because it's not exported. `export IFS` to export it.

> Is it just a global variable?

Yes, it is a global variable, as in, the scope of the variable is not limited to a function. It may be, it's common to do `local IFS` for function local modifications.

> IFS="C" bash -c 'echo X"$IFS"X' if it is an variale, why this line command not override it?

The same way:

```
$ PWD="C" bash -c 'echo X${PWD}X'
X/home/kamilX
```

Bash ignores that exported values of `IFS` and uses its own value, which *also Bash* reports with variable expansion. Still, the exported value is there, you just can't access it with Bash:

```
$ IFS="C" python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["IFS"])'
C
```

> how to check whether a variable is global or environ?

You can check if the variable has `x` attribute set with `declare -p`.

```
$ declare -p IFS
declare -- IFS=" 
"
$ export IFS
$ declare -p IFS
declare -x IFS=" 
"
```

---

And source code, from https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/9439ce094c9aa7557a9d53ac7b412a23aa66e36b/variables.c#L531 :

```
  /* Don't allow IFS to be imported from the environment. */
  temp_var = bind_variable ("IFS", " \t\n", 0);
  setifs (temp_var);
```

And https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/9439ce094c9aa7557a9d53ac7b412a23aa66e36b/subst.c#L11092 and https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/9439ce094c9aa7557a9d53ac7b412a23aa66e36b/variables.c#L5741 . It is handled specially - some internal Bash variables for word splitting are initialized depending on IFS value.

Comment: But this `a="C" bash -c 'echo X${a}X'`  will show `XCX`, I konw in bash, envrion variable expands prior to global variable.

Comment: I do not understand that `envrion variable expands prior to global variable` part. Variable expansion happens "at the same time" for exported and not exported variables and function local and non-local variables. `But this a="C" bash -c 'echo X${a}X' will show XCX` Yes, and `LINENO=C bash -c 'echo $LINENO'` will output 1. There are special variables that ignore set or exported values. Bash literally does `if (variable_name == "LINENO") { expand_it_to_line_number(); } else...`

Comment: Maybe like this, for example, you can also do `$ env "var,with,comma,in,name=123" bash -c 'echo ${there_is_no_way_to_output_that_var}; env | grep var,'` and it's not possible to output environment variables with comma in the name, but it's there.